# Executing system commands in terminal / command prompt from Mozilla add-on

Tags: javascript, macos, terminal, mozilla, add-on

I am creating an add-on for Mozilla.
I have seen that if I know the path of a file, I can execute it by spawning the process.
But is it possible to execute system commands like "ls", "dir", "javac" etc. from my mozilla add-on directly?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I have found a way to run .bat and .sh file in windows and Linux through my Mozilla Add-on using javascript. But is there a way to run .sh file in Mac?

Below I have mentioned some code to show how I am doing that for Linux.

```
var exefile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                 .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    /**
     * Path to terminal file.
     * I need same for Mac.
     */
    exefile.initWithPath("/usr/bin/gnome-terminal"); 

var run = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/process/util;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
    run.init(exefile);
var parameters = ["-e", path_of_shell_script]; //with arguments
    run.run(false, parameters,parameters.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not into these kind of concepts. But the question is a bit intriguing. So, i peeped into it.

Well If you can call the file then you can call an batch file or shell script which will do the trick for you.

Comment: Yes, but I want to pass the command directly.
Something like Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac"); in Java.